# -bash: __git_ps1: command not found: Mac User Big Sur 11.4

Tags: bash

Hello I am a beginner learning JS, I was following a class, when I started to get this error in my terminal:**-bash: __git_ps1: command not found**. I am stuck now I have read on how to fix this and tried a few different things, but I really do not know what im doing and do not want to screw up my computer. I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue. I really need line by line directions to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We can't fix it with certainty without knowing how you caused it. That said, there's a good chance you may just need to replace your `PS1` with a value that doesn't try to call the missing function. (A _good chance_, not a certainty, because sometimes folks install pre-prompt hooks that modify or update PS1 dynamically, and if you have one of those it'll just put the call back after you remove it)

Comment: In general, for questions about how to configure and use UNIX systems as opposed to how to develop software, [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) tends to be more appropriate. git questions are specifically on-topic here, but even though the specific prompt function you're having trouble with is git-related, how to install and uninstall such functions is _not_.

Comment: ...another possibility, is that you `export`ed your PS1, but _didn't_ export a function it depends on. It's best not to export PS1 at all -- the format is different between different shells, so processes that inherit a value designed for a different shell may not interpret it correctly. (Similarly, the way exported functions are represented in environment variables is entirely shell-specific, so those can't be expected to work when switching across shells either).

Comment: Anyhow -- start by inspecting `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. If you see anything redefining PS1, comment it out; then start a new Terminal window and check whether that fixed things.

Comment: Ok...I inspected ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile. I am getting a permission denied when I enter these commands? Not sure how to fix that issue.

Comment: -rw-------    1 drewjr  staff     6164 Jun  9 09:48 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 drewjr  staff      688 May 30 18:58 .bash_profile
-rw-------    1 drewjr  staff      922 Jun  1 09:32 .bash_profile.save
-rw-------    1 drewjr  staff      922 Jun  1 09:32 .bash_profile.save.1
-rw-------    1 drewjr  staff      809 Jun  1 09:35 .bash_profile.save.2
drwx------  207 drewjr  staff     6624 Jun  9 09:48 .bash_sessions
-rw-r--r--    1 drewjr  staff      166 Jun  1 10:02 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--    1 drewjr  staff    78657 Jun  1 09:59 git-completion.bash

Comment: Those aren't commands to run, they're files to edit. Open them in a programmer's text editor, whichever one you use.

Comment: Ya so that lest comment actually helped me figure this out; I went in and edited the file that I changed and fixed the issue. Thank you to CD.